# Objective C - Image size is larger

Tags: objective-c, image, png, jpeg

I am moving to Objective C from Java, for a Mac application. It's an screen sharing application.

Upon analysing, I found that, size of the image created using Objective C is larger than the one created using Java. I intend to use JPEG for desktop & other image windows and  8-bit PNG for browser/explorer windows. For both formats, Java is better(i.e., lesser image size).

E.g., : When I create a JPEG image with 0.6 compression factor, the size of the image created using Java is 103KB. The same image, when created using Objective C, it is 201KB.

Is there any way to optimise the image size so that the image created using Objective C is same or lesser than the one created using Java?

Objective C code used

```
NSSize imageSize = [image size]; [image lockFocus]; NSRect imageRect =
NSMakeRect(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height); NSBitmapImageRep*
myBitmapImageRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc]
initWithFocusedViewRect:imageRect]; [image unlockFocus]; NSDictionary*
options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithDouble:imageCompression], NSImageCompressionFactor,
                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], NSImageProgressive,
                                 nil]; NSData* imageData = [myBitmapImageRep representationUsingType:fileType
properties:options];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the compression factor (a.k.a quality factor) scale is the same between both environments? e.g. with `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` (iOS API) a `compressionQuality` parameter of `0.75` gives a quality factor of `93`.

If I were you I'd first check that the quality factor is the same on both images, e.g. use ImageMagick:

```
identify -format "%Q" myimage.jpg
```

If quality factors are the same on both images, you need to check which JPEG encoding option(s) differ(s) - here again ImageMagick `identify` is your friend.

Comment: After a long struggle, I installed imagemagick. But I am getting the following error

Assertion failed: (dec->numcomps == 3), function jpc_dec_tiledecode, file jpc_dec.c, line 1077.
Abort trap: 6

Comment: It sounds as if your jasper library is quite old (this [bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=469786) has been patched for a while now). That being said: are your working with JPEG-2000 files? I assumed you were working with (basic) JPEG files...

Comment: I tried both - basic JPEG and JPEG2000. I am getting the response for JPEG created using Java. But I am getting the above error when I try "indentify" for the JPEG/JPEG2000 created using Objective C?

$ identify -format "%Q" java-1358420666033.jpg 
60

Comment: My answer was nothing more than a suggestion used to make sure you were using the same options (and most importantly the same quality factor) while encoding your basic JPEG file on Java vs Objective-C. Perhaps you should edit your question and elaborate a bit more so that it gives some more precisions and point out you are trying to use JPEG-2000 too so that others can help.